# PHP memory behavior in function with reference parameters

Tags: php, memory-leaks

Will a PHP function with optional reference parameters leak memory if a value is assigned inside the function to a nonexistent parameter?

For eg.

```
function TestA(?array &$rInput = null) : bool {
    if ($rInput === null) {
        $tempArray = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
            $tempArray[] = $i;
        }
        
        $rInput = $tempArray;
    }
    
    return true;
}


$result = TestA();
```

Thank your for your input!

Comment: No, PHP has a garbage collector.

Comment: Once it's out of scope, it would be cleaned up as needed https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: In general, you don't care about memory leaks in PHP coming from the underlying C runtime. If they ever happen, they're bugs in PHP itself and there's little you can do from your PHP code.